# How do Christian Scientists respond to the jellyfish argument?

Tags: christian-science

Christian Scientists believe that illness is caused by a mental error, rather than a physical abnormality. In other words, that all diseases are psychosomatic. Critics say that, if that were true, animals without a brain (and thus without a mind) could never get ill. But jellyfish, animals without a brain, can and do get diseases such as cancer. How do Christian Scientists respond to that argument?

Comment: I’m not a member of Christian Science, but if I had to guess they’d say this only applies to humans as rational animals? If I remember correctly Christian scientists are idealists, meaning they would rely on conscience experience to explain spiritual realities. Therefore animals such as jellyfish would not fit under this category. I’m just speculating though.

Comment: @LukeHill Do you think that Christian scientists would deny that non-human animals and humans suffer from the same diseases? That they would claim that cancers we get are somehow different from cancers non-human animals get?

Comment: No, I don’t think they’d deny that. More likely I think what the may say (again speculation off the little I know/remember) is that it’s our original sin in adam and our fault that led to their sickness. This could have originated from a mental state previously described.

Comment: @LukeHill I think Christian Scientists do not take Genesis literally.

Comment: That’s possible - as I said I’m not aware of much besides some of their views in idealism and sickness